# How to clear hostile mob drops only

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a set up to kill all hostile mobs the minute they spawn on my server, should I just always have a /clear kind of command running? Or is there an alternative way to make it so people can get stuff from mining and such?

Answer (score 2):

You can make mobs drop no drops when getting killed by doing:

```
/gamerule doMobLoot false
```

That way mobs don't drop anything when getting killed but your players can't get any mobdrops either. Hopefully this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could kill only drops in an area, like this:

```
/kill @e[type=item,x=?,y=?,z=?,dx=?,dy=?,dz=?]
```

Replace the question marks with the lowest X, Y and Z coordinates of an imaginary box around all the items you want to kill and the size of that box in X, Y and Z direction.